# methods outside of constructor in c#

Tags: c#, class, object, methods, constructor

I am working on some study materials and came across some code I don't understand.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var warrior = new Samurai();
        warrior.Attack("the evildoers");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    class Sword
    {
        public void Hit(string target)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Chopped {0} clean in half", target);
        }
    }

    class Samurai
    {
        readonly Sword sword;
        public Samurai()
        {
            this.sword = new Sword();
        }

        public void Attack(string target)
        {
            this.sword.Hit(target);
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I am concerned, when I instantiated Samurai, I run the method `public Samurai()`. How is the method `warrior.Attack` called if the `Attack` method was outside of the constructor `public Samurai()`?

Comment: `public Samurai()` is a constructor of the `Samurai` class, not a method. The method `Attack()` is already outside of the constructor hence I am confused by what you actually want to know.

Comment: and adding to the above comment you are calling the Attack method via the object of the Samurai class

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. Do you not understand why `warrior.Attack("the evildoers");` calls `Samurai`'s `Attack` method, or do you not understand the process by which this is done?

Comment: I must say @d1du you should read OOP basic concepts

Comment: `public Samurai()` is the constructor of the `Samurai` class, and `public void Attack` is in that class. Therefore, you can call `Attack` on an instance of `Samurai` that you create via `new Samurai()`.

Comment: @Blorgbeard thanks for the clarification. I thought ````new Samurai()```` would only run the line ````this.sword = new Sword()```` and since the ````Attack```` method was outside of ````public Samurai()````, I thought it could not be accessed by a new instance of Samurai.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor of the Samurai class is actually

```
public Samurai()
{
    this.sword = new Sword();
}
```

What this means is that when you write this code below:

```
var warrior = new Samurai();
```

You create a new instance of a Samurai class, and the code in the Samurai class constructor is executed. i.e. an instance of a Sword is created for this Samurai (this.sword = new Sword()).

The Sword class does not contain a constructor, so when an instance of a Sword is created by the Samurai constructor, nothing else in the Sword class is called.

```
new Samurai();
```

is how you create an instance of a Samurai class.

By using

```
var warrior = new Samurai();
```

You are creating an instance of the Samurai class AND also declaring a variable called "warrior", which will be your reference to this newly created instance.

So whenever you want to call the "Attack" method of this newly created instance, you can use your code:

```
warrior.Attack("the evildoers");
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification!